# Capture video in Java for Freebsd

Tags: java

Please help! I need a Java library that can create captures using 3gp files and it should work in Freebsd. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMF for that. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html

refer this code to capture video. But you need to code for 3gp format.http://www.mutong.com/fischer/java/usbcam/

Comment: I do not need to play this video. I need to take only snapshots and as far as I know jmf does not support 3gp files

Comment: you can capture video using JMF. Then You have convert into 3gp file format.

Comment: I need something like xuggle. But xuggle does not work with Freebsd.

Comment: I look for a utility or library. I sent 3gp file as a parameter and program makes frames(captures) and store it in file system.

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions. ffmpeg and vlc programs.